# Acces custom Doctrine Manager in a Symfony2 Service

Tags: symfony, service, request, entitymanager

I don´t know how to do this,

I create a service in Symfony2 and i need to this service use request and doctrine entitymanager service

In services.yml i add these lines:

```
    logdb:
      class:     %logdb.class%
      arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager','@request_injector']
```

My service class:

```
class LogDB {

protected $em;
protected $request;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em, Request $request){

    $this->em= $em;
    $this->request= $request;
}

public function saveLog(){

}
```

}

Well, in saveLog() i need to acces to entitymanager but from a different manager of default, i mean entity manager i am injecting with '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager' is default.

In a controller i can do this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($this->getRequest()->get('shop'));
```

I use differents databases for every shop, that i choose by url param.
Ask is, how can i acces to a custom entitymanager from a service?

injecting container is a bad solution...

maybe i need to pass entitymanager as argument in every service method from controller i don´t know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you are injecting the wrong Object. Why not inject doctrine to the service?

```
services:
    logdb:
       class:     %logdb.class%
       arguments: ['@doctrine','@request_injector']
                   # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^- not the entity_manager
```

Then you can call this in your `service`:

```
$em = $this->doctrine->getManager($this->request);
```

Comment: thanks, it works, wich class is used for doctrine, i mean in class __construct(¿class? $doctrine, Request $request)

Comment: It is an instance of `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry` don't forget to add a `use` statement